# How to use startInstrumentation() with socket permission enabled?

Tags: android, instrumentation

**[The background]**

I have been able to use the instrumentation in Android test projects. But now, I am trying to use instrumentation in normal Android app in order to do some automatic GUI control. For example, there is an app X in which instrumentation is used to start app Y and to send virtual keys/touch/click events into app Y. I successfully did it with one activity and one class derived from Instrumentation. These 2 classes are created in one app project. The activity is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        String pack = new String("com.example.appX.MainActivity");
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this,
                                               FilterInstrumentation.class);
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("package", pack);
        startInstrumentation(name, null, arguments);
        ...
    }
}
```

The instrumentation sub class is like this:

```
public class FilterInstrumentation extends Instrumentation {
    public void onStart(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setClassName(getTargetContext(), pack);
        Activity activity = startActivitySync(intent);
    }
    ...
}
```

**[The problem]**

The activity and the instrumentation are working successfully. A TCP server is also made to receive commands from external network in order to control the instrument's behaviors. I met the following 2 problems:

**Problem 1** when the TCP server in the activity: Sockets can be created but the activity and the instrument can't talk to each other because "startInstrumentation()" is starting the instrument in a new standalone process. The activity can't get the instance of the "FilterInstrumentation" class. Commands received by the TCP server can't be sent to the instrument easily.

**Problem 2** when the TCP server in the FilterInstrumentation. It will failed to create sockets due to the permission issue as "java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)". FilterInstrumentation is running in a dynamically created process, I can't control the permission by Manifest.xml file.

It seems that the test framework of Android can run an instrument in the same process but I don't know how to do this within my code without test framework used.

Can any master give any helpful info on this?

Thanks in advance.